# const map & as function argument

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I am trying to make function to fill map with random values, but i am getting this error:

```
 passing 'const std::map<int,char>' as 'this' argument of
 'std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const_Key,_Tp>, etc.
```

function:

```
void mapInit(const map<int,char> &mp)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      int x = rand() % 100;
      char c = 'a' + rand() % 10;
      pair<int,char> p;
      p = make_pair(x,c);

      mp.insert(p);
   }
}
```

How should I understand this?

Comment: Why would you think that it's better to not paste the entire message? Do you also abbreviate other sentences like this? "Hi, I'm calling to inform you that there's a problem with, etc."

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am writing code in other computer when I dont have access to internet and didnt want to rewrite all massage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to `insert` into the `map`, it certainly cannot be `const`. Inserting is a mutating operation. Change the signature to

```
void mapInit(map<int,char>& mp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want to insert elements into the map, you cannot use const. 
Secondly, you should use for example uniform_int_distribution instead of c-style rand().

Example:

```
class rand_int
{
public:
    rand_int(int l, int h) : p{l, h} {};
    int operator()() const {return r();}
private:
    uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type p;
    function<int()> r = bind(uniform_int_distribution<>{p}, default_random_engine{});
};
```